# Seltsamer Genitiv

Tags: genitive

In einem Theaterflyer las ich neulich folgendes:

> Ein Stück über Blüte und Fall eines von uns

Darüber stolpertete ich. Meine Freundin auch. Es klingt nach wie vor falsch für uns.

Ist das richtiges Deutsch und klingt nur seltsam oder ist das unzulässig?
Gibt es ähnliche Beispiele?

Comment: Spontan würde ich sagen: Klingt seltsam, müßte aber richtig gebildet sein. Ich würde auf _von_ ausweichen, auch wenn dann die Doppelung klappert.

Comment: Noch ein Einfall: _Blüte und Fall eines der Unseren_ wäre OK, nur ist _die Unseren_ arg hochgestochen.

Comment: Es gab aber nicht noch etwas Kleingedrucktes ala "...Blüte und Fall eines von uns _liebgewonnen Mädchens_" ? Ansonsten klingt es für mich im ersten Moment auch merkwürdig.

Comment: Aber wie in "eines von den Blättern", benötigt der Ausdruck "eines von X" wohl den Dativ für X, und damit wäre "eines von uns" richtig - theoretisch.

Comment: Was stört Dich denn? Ich sehe kein Problem. Jedenfalls ist „eines von uns“ inhaltlich das gleiche wie „von einem von uns“, nur mit echtem Genitiv. Hier übrigens das Plakat: [link](http://www.zitty.de/narr-aus-der-rue-lacine-die-ernsthafte-komodie-uber-blute-und-fall-eines-von-uns-2.html)

Comment: Es klingt etwas seltsam, ist aber wohl korrekt.

Comment: Mich stört nichts, aber es gibt zumindestens einige Muttersprachler, für die diese Konstruktion seltsam kling. Grammatik (allg. die Wissenschaft von der Sprache) richtet sich nach der Sprache, nicht umgedreht. Falls es genug Sprecher gibt, die etwas als komisch empfinden, gehört die Grammatik geändert. Ich denke aber nicht, dass das hier der Fall ist.

Comment: Meine Frage war an den ursprünglichen Fragesteller gerichtet; tut mir leid, wenn das missverständlich war.
Wenn es einigen Muttersprachlern merkwürdig vorkommt, mag es einfach daran liegen, dass diese solche Konstruktionen nicht mehr gewohnt sind.

Comment: Komisch ist etwas, dass zum Lachen oder Schmunzeln reizt. Etwas bloß ungewohntes ist dagegen seltsam.

Comment: @user unknown: in meinem Sprachgebrauch ist das nicht mehr so und der Duden hat die "neue" Bedeutung auch aufgenommen. Seltsam zu verwenden wäre seltsam für mich. Ich kann dir aber "stranger" als Alternative anbieten ;)

Comment: Ich glaube, bluoranges erster Kommentar kann etwas mit dem stolpern zu tun haben - "eines von uns liebgewonnenen Mädchens" o.ä. ist eine verbreitetere Form, und die auf dem Plakat wirkt deswegen abgehackt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Konstruktion ist richtig, was (hoffentlich) ersichtlich wird, wenn man sie in gebräuchlichere Konstruktionen zerlegt (»Blüte und Fall eines Menschen.« – »Er ist einer von uns.«) oder Worte ersetzt (»Blüte und Fall eines von ihnen«).

Was ein Grund dafür sein könnte, dass es seltsam wirkt, ist, dass zwei verschiedene Konstruktionen genutzt werden, um die Zugehörigkeit anzuzeigen, nämlich einmal der Genitiv (eines) und einmal *von* + Dativ (von uns), und zwar ohne dass hierfür eine Notwendigkeit besteht. Vermutlich deswegen wirkt *eines der Unsrigen* besser und sogar *von einem von uns* (trotz Wortdoppelung und »von-Genitiv«).

---

Nachtrag:

Die Struktur der Konstruktion »Blüte und Fall eines von uns« ist wie folgt:

- »eines von uns« ist Genitiv von »einer von uns« und beantwortet, um wessen »Blüte und Fall« es geht. Hierbei handelt es sich bei »einer« um ein Indefinitpronomen oder Numerale (was von beiden ist irrelevant, da alle Formen identisch sind).
- »von uns« spezifiziert »eines« und ist eine von+Dativ-Konstruktion, die einen Genitiv ersetzt, der beantwortet, wessen »eines« ist. Dieser Genitiv wäre »unser« und würde zu der unverständlichen Konstruktion »einer unser« führen, weswegen er zu ersetzen ist, z. B. durch »der Unsrigen« oder eben »von uns«. (In »Vater unser« existiert eine vergleichbare Konstruktion noch ohne Ersetzung.)

Answer (score 4):

Lustig, wie manche grammatikalisch korrekten Formulierungen komisch klingen, nur weil sie nicht häufig verwendet werden, oder?

> Er ist **einer von uns**
>   Das gehört **einem von uns**
>   Ich sehe **einen von uns**

werfen keinerlei Fragen auf, aber

> Die Freundin **eines von uns**

klingt komisch, ist aber grammatikatlisch völlig korrekt gebildet.

Answer (score 0):

Das Wort »Fall« könnte mehrere Bedeutungen haben.
Nicht gemeint ist »Fall« als Bezeichnung eines von mehreren gleichwertigen Dingen (»Der Ankläger im Fall „Müller gegen Schneider“ möge bitte vortreten«), sondern der Fall als Gegenteil des Aufstieges (»Aufstieg und Fall der Stadt Mahagonny«), denn die »Blüte« bezeichnet hier wohl die Hochphase zwischen Aufstieg und Fall.

Auch fällt auf, dass es sich hier nicht um einen ganzen Satz handelt, sondern nur um das Objekt eines Satzes. Es handelt sich also um eine Ellipse, wobei Subjekt und Prädikat weggelassen sind. Das ist weder ein Fehler noch schlechtes Deutsch, sondern einfach nur ein gängiges Stilmittel. Der ganze Satz könnte ungefähr so lauten:

> *Wir spielen* ein Stück über Blüte und Fall eines von uns.

Das ist völlig korrektes Deutsch. Klarer (aber weniger poetisch) wird es, wenn man Artikel einfügt:

> Wir spielen ein Stück über *die* Blüte und *den* Fall eines von uns.

Man kann das auch in zwei Sätzen mit identischem Aufbau formulieren:

> Wir spielen ein Stück über die Blüte eines von uns.
>   Wir spielen ein Stück über den Fall eines von uns.

Um das Akkusativobjekt eines der beiden Sätze näher zu analysieren, kann man es in einen anderen Satz einbauen, der den Blick auf das Wesentliche lenkt:

> Wir betrachten den Fall eines von uns.

Um die eingangs besprochene Doppeldeutigkeit des Wortes »Fall« zu vermeiden, kann man es durch ein Synonym ersetzen:

> Wir betrachten den *Niedergang* eines von uns.

Um die Rolle des Genitivobjekts, welches das Akkusativobjekt näher beschreibt, besser verstehen zu können, kann man es durch ein anderes Genitivobjekt ersetzen:

> Wir betrachten den Niedergang *des Herrn Weber*.

Spätestens dieser Satz sollte sich nicht mehr irgendwie schräg anfühlen. Da er aber schrittweise und unter Beibehaltung der wichtigen grammatikalischen Strukturen aus dem Ausgangssatz entwickelt wurde, sollte nun auch der Ausgangssatz verständlicher sein.